# Using Firebase to populate TableviewCell with Collectionview inside

Tags: swift, database, firebase, uitableview, uicollectionview

I can populate my TableviewCell with images and upload them to Firebase successfully but not to my CollectionView inside the cell. However, I can upload them to a CollectionView on another ViewController as long as it's not inside a TableViewCell. I experimented with reloading the data but nothing appears and isn't required by the one on the other ViewController. I'm trying to get the "showcaseImages" to appear in the collectionView.

**This is what I have to save the data in my structure:**

```
func save ( userInfo: UserInfo, completion: @escaping (Result < Bool, NSError>) -> Void) {
        
        var showcaseImagesDict = [String : String]()
        userInfo.showcaseImages.forEach { showcaseImagesDict[UUID().uuidString] = $0 }
        
        userReference.addDocument(data: ["profileImage": userInfo.profileImage, "profileName": userInfo.profileName, "showcaseImages": showcaseImagesDict
        
        ]) { (error) in
            if let unwrappedError = error {
                completion(.failure(unwrappedError as NSError))
            }else {
                completion(.success(true))
            }
        }
    }
```

**This is what I have to Listen:**

```
func listen (completion : @escaping ([UserInfo]) -> Void) {
        userReference.addSnapshotListener { (snapshot, error) in
            guard let unwrappedSnapshot = snapshot else {return}
            let documents = unwrappedSnapshot.documents
            var usersInfo = [UserInfo]()
            for document in documents {
                let documentData = document.data()
                guard
                let profileImage = documentData["profileImage"] as? String,
                let profileName = documentData["profileName"] as? String,
                let showcaseImagesDict = documentData["showcaseImages"] as? [String : String]
                else {continue}
                
                let showcaseImages = showcaseImagesDict.map {$0.value}
                let userInfo = UserInfo(profileImage: profileImage, profileName: profileName, showcaseImages: showcaseImages)
                usersInfo.append(userInfo)
            }
            completion(usersInfo)
        }
    }
```

**Heres what I have to populate the TableviewCell:**

```
func populate(with user: UserInfo){
            profileName.text = user.profileName
            imageCache2?.getImage(named: user.profileImage,completion: { [weak self](image) in
                self?.userImage.image = image
                //self?.user = user
    
            })
        }
```

**This is to populate CollectionViewCell:**

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "CVCell", for: indexPath)
        let collectionViewCell1 = cell as? CollectionViewCell
        collectionViewCell1?.imageCache4 = imageCache3
        let imagePath = showcaseImages[indexPath.item]
        collectionViewCell1?.populate(with: imagePath)
        return cell
    }
```